# C# System.IO.NetworkStream Read/Write Race Condition

Tags: c#, multithreading, server, stream

I have a WebSocket Server that uses the System.IO.Stream class to communicate (1 Stream per connection). The server needs to send and receive, (C# .NET 2.0) and the Stream object is created from the generated TcpClient when I accept a connection.

The desired setup is I have Stream.Read on one thread handling all the incoming messages. It's a loop where Stream.Read() is expected to block as messages come in.

On another thread, I need to occasionally send messages back to the client using Stream.Write().

My question is, would there ever be a race condition? Is it possible when I fire off a Stream.Write() while Stream.Read() is waiting/reading that I could muddle up the incoming read data? or is Stream smart enough to lock up the resources for me? Is there any case where having these two sitting on Read() and Write() at the same time could break things?

Answer (score 0):

After some more research, it turns out it's a NetworkStream object. Which does indeed handle synchronous read/write without a race condition:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream(v=vs.110).aspx

> Read and write operations can be performed simultaneously on an instance of the NetworkStream class without the need for synchronization. As long as there is one unique thread for the write operations and one unique thread for the read operations, there will be no cross-interference between read and write threads and no synchronization is required."